# lynx dump -- use color?

Tags: dump, lynx

I just tried...

```
lynx -dump -list_inline "http://www.samplepage.com"
```

to get a formatted output of a web page.  However, I noticed that for links, only the starting point is marked but not the end point.  For instance, for something like this

```
this is <a href="www.link.com">a link</a> somewhere
```

I get

```
this is [www.link.com]a link somewhere
```

but what I would like to get is something like

```
this is [www.link.com]a link[endlink] somewhere
```

so that I know what portion of the text exactly is included in the link.  Does anybody have an idea how this could be done?

Thank you very much for your help!

Best regards,
Florian